# how to set up a git repository which can be accessed by network in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: git

Now we want to set up a private git repository in the ubuntu 12.10,then other developments can access it through the local network.

Now I just can create a repository use `git init`,for example:

```
cd myproject
git init
```

Which will create .git directory,but I do not know how to access it thougth network like:

```
git://192.168.1.1/myproject/.git
```

Any idea?

BTW,I have tried:

```
git init --bare
```

which will give me a error:

```
git add error : "fatal : malloc, out of memory"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

installing GIT just gives your linux machine the software to handle a GIT reporitory on the machine. The difference between a local GIT repository and a master network repository, is the master network repository can be accessed over the network.

So, you need to setup an account on the server for the clients to SSH into, and setup details to match on all the clients. This page has some info that looks about right. (disclaimer - I haven't followed these actual steps in this particular howto myself but they are what I expect them to be off the top of my head)

http://tumblr.intranation.com/post/766290565/how-set-up-your-own-private-git-server-linux

PS: for the failing repository init command, try this:

```
git --bare init
```

instead of

```
git init --bare
```